# Finding the time stamp of when a USB storage device was inserted on a Windows system

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, windows-registry

I know that it is possible to read the registry files on a windows system and find out the details of a USB storage device that was inserted in the system. This can be done by reading `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB` from the registry.

Now, my question - Is it possible to find the exact time stamp of when a particular storage device was inserted on a windows system (Windows 7 to be specific) by reading registry values? If yes, then how can we do that?

Comment: Is using a third party tool acceptable? Try http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_log_view.html

Comment: No, without using a third party tool, if possible.